# $routeProvider not redirecting to templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I am creating some CRUD pages using AngularJS and on a list of Users page, I am trying redirect to edit page once the user click on "`Edit`" button. But for some reason `$routeProvider` is not working.

Here is my `index.html` showing list of users

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in usersData">
    <td>{{ user.firstname }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.jobtitle }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.userprofile.sex }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.userprofile.maritalstatus }}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="editUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">edit</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

My `app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('benefitApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/editUser/:userId", {
                templateUrl : "templates/editUser.html"
            });
});

app.controller('userController', ['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope, $http, $location) {
  $http.get("https://localhost:8443/benefits/v1/users/").then(function (response){
      $scope.usersData = response.data;
  });
  $scope.editUser = function(userId) {    
      $location.path('/editUser/' + userId);
  }
}]);
```

My directory structure is as below

```
src/main/resources/static/js/app.js
src/main/resources/static/css/bootstrap.css
src/main/resources/templates/index.html
src/main/resources/templates/editUser.html
```

What am i missing? On click of "Edit" button, the url in the browser changes to `https://localhost:8443/home#!/editUser/1`, but it never gets routed to `editUser.html`

Comment: Try `home/editUser/:userid`. Better yet, use $location's html5 mode: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Comment: @SimonPoole - doesn't work ...I tried to add $locationProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, by moving my templates to views folder that I created under static folder.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){  
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/listUser', {templateUrl: 'views/listUser.html', controller: 'userController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/listCompany',{templateUrl: 'views/listCompany.html', controller: 'companyController'});
    $routeProvider
        .when('/editUser/:userId', {
                templateUrl : 'views/editUser.html'
            })
            ;   
    $routeProvider
        .when('/editCompany/:companyId', {
            templateUrl : 'views/editCompany.html'
        })
        ;
    $routeProvider.when('/createUser',{templateUrl:'views/createUser.html'});
    $routeProvider.when('/createCompany',{templateUrl:'views/createCompany.html'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this and ng-view directive `$location.path('editUser/' + userId);`

Comment: Still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the ng-view directive inside your app so that the $route service can render the correct template.

Comment: I added this , still no change. It's a same output